# USB mouse that has worked well with an iMac, PC and Chromebook isn’t working on MacBook Air

Tags: usb, mouse, macbook-air, wireless-mouse

I have had a wireless optical mouse ([VicTsing Computer Wireless Mouse, 2.4G Portable USB Mouse Ergonomic Mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074DV98R7)) for about two years and it has worked completely fine on a Chromebook, an iMac and a PC (not sure anything about it because it's my friends).

For some reason though when I tried it on this MacBook Air running macOS 10.15.2 (Catalina), it won’t work.

When I first tried to plug it in, it recognized it as a keyboard and shot me over to the keyboard settings but every time I’ve plugged it in after that it hasn’t done anything.

I've messed around with just about every setting in the keyboard and mouse sections in system preferences, and I also got [SteerMouse](https://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), which could show me that my mouse was plugging in and that it was connected and fine, but it still didn’t work.

There’s probably something really obvious that i've overlooked, but for now I have no clue.

Comment: Catalina is 64-bit only. Maybe it does not have a driver for your mouse.  Is it possible to try a newer USB Mouse?